# Change heroku default npm start

Tags: heroku, procfile

I understand that I need to set a procfile where I can change the default settings, I want to run npm staging instead of npm start here I have my scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server",
    "staging": "NODE_ENV=staging node server",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=testing jest --verbose --coverage --silent",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server"
  },
```

I just want to change this setting in one specific dyno of heroku not all of them.

Comment: "I just want to change this setting in one specific dyno of heroku not all of them"—that's not how dynos work. Are you trying to set up a [staging environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)?

Comment: yes that's my plan, to set that up in heroku

Comment: Great! Have you read the documentation I linked to? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I did Chris and it did helped thanks for your help :D